# How to remove observer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, addobserver

I have an ARC enabled project

There are few observers added in **viewDidLoad**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(getSipNotification:) name:@"getSipNotification" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(syncExtensionData:) name:@"syncExtensionData" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showLocalNotification:) name:@"showLocalNotification" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(outgoingCall:)  name:@"outgoingCall" object:nil]; 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playRingtone)  name:@"playRingtone" object:nil];
```

I want to remove all observers so I added following line in **viewDidUnload**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Now my question is, is this remove all observers?

If not how can do it?

**UPDATE**

If I want to remove a single observer how can do it?

Can you help me please.

Comment: Yes it remove all observers :)

Comment: Please note that viewDidUnload: isn't a right place for removing observer in most cases. Most likely you should do it in dealloc, viewDidDissapear or something else.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It will remove all observers.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

And you can remove a particular observer like this...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"syncExtensionData" object:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

In my application i used this notification :

for particular observer remove this way :

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceRotatedFeedBackView:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

}
-(void)deviceRotatedFeedBackView:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    //right whetever you want
}
 - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}
```

may be it will helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it'll remove all the observers in your class.

You can use following to remove single observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"getSipNotification" object:nil];
```

To remove individual observer.

Answer (score 0):

viewDidUnload is deprecated in iOS6 and later, so Your observer never be removed from notification center in iOS6 and later. To remove single observer try

> ```
>  - (void)removeObserver:(id)notificationObserver name:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender
> ```